# How do I install Antergos with a GTX 970?

Tags: nvidia, antergos

My understanding is that the GTX 970 is too new for the nouveau driver currently. The official NVIDIA binary supports it, though. Is it possible for me to install the latest version of Antergos? If I try to launch the Live version, I get a bunch of terminal output (good things) followed by an endlessly black screen. I assume that is the failed display driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my troubleshooting (with [the help of Antergos](http://forum.antergos.com/topic/2302/booting-from-usb-results-in-black-screen-gtx-970)), I have solved the issue.

First, install using the minimal ISO as it requires no hardware accelerated graphics. Reboot as instructed by the installer.

Second, edit the boot option in GRUB; add the following to the call to start the kernel.

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

This starts the system in the CLI. Using the following commands (as root), remove the nouveau driver and install the NVIDIA one.

```
pacman -Syy nvidia nvidia-utils nvidia-libgl
pacman -Rccn xf86-video-nouveau
nvidia-xconfig
```

Say "yes" when it asks about handling a conflict.

Reboot. Start the system normally. The desktop will be properly hardware accelerated.