# Crashing during installation of any linux distribution

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, system-installation

I'm running a Windows 10 setup on an SSD and want to install a Linux Distribution on another SSD plugged into the same machine. I've tried with both Fedora and Ubuntu, using both Rufus and Fedora Writer. I've got Secure Boot disabled and run Legacy+UEFI boot.

When I boot from the USB drive I create, everything looks fine and I can choose to install or run live image. No matter which one I choose, I wind up with a screen looking something like below:
[image]

Any ideas?
Let me know if any additional information is able to bring clarity to the situation.

I'm running:
Z97 GAMING 5
GTX 970
i7 4790k
16gb of ram

Windows 10 on an Samsung 850SSD, wanting to install on a spare Samsung 830SSD. I have previously had Linux installs on the 830 with the remainder of the system the same.

Comment: can you provide details on the hardware itself you are running on? make, model, video components, etc.

Comment: @0xSheepdog Updated with some HW specs

Comment: thanks. I don't see any obvious hardware issues off the bat; I ask because I encountered a similar problem years ago when the popular distro kernel versions did not yet include Intel Iris HD drivers, but it was on my board. i'll keep mulling this over...

Comment: darn it - well thanks for chippin' in nonetheless!

Comment: **update** Am able to boot the installers using 'nomodeset' option, but the following installer for Fedora results in an unbootable system and for Ubuntu a system that I can only boot into using nomodeset, giving a very choppy ui.

Comment: I ended up installing in a manner similar to that mentioned in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207895/how-do-i-install-antergos-with-a-gtx-970

Comment: @EmilL. perhaps you should consider answering your own question. This is actually [encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it) for SE sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the commands described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207895/how-do-i-install-antergos-with-a-gtx-970) to get NVidia drivers up and running before doing anything else with the system. To boot succesfully I also had to add the [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) flag.